# Error in using DeepFilterNet for audio denoising

Tags: python, machine-learning, audio, deep-learning, signal-processing

I am trying to use DeepFilterNet to denoise an audio, I am getting an `The system cannot find the file specified` error while using API as well as while following the command given on their official [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Rikorose/DeepFilterNet).

**API code**:

```
import requests

r = requests.post(url='https://hf.space/embed/hshr/DeepFilterNet/+/api/predict/', json={"data": [{"data": None, "is_example": True, "name": "none"},
                                                                                                 {"data": None, "is_example": True, "name": "samples/chat_with_noise.wav"},
                                                                                                 {"data": None, "is_example": True, "name": "samples/dkitchen.wav"},
                                                                                                 10]}) 
print(r.json())
```

The above code throws an error, which says:

```
> warnings.warn("No audio backend is available.")
> 
> {'error': "[Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'samples/chat_with_noise.wav'"}
```

**Terminal Code:**

```
# Install cpu/cuda pytorch (>=1.8) dependency from pytorch.org, e.g.:
pip install torch torchaudio -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html
# Install DeepFilterNet
pip install deepfilternet
deepFilter samples/chat_with_noise.wav
```

which throws an error

```
> warnings.warn("No audio backend is available.") 
>
> 2022-10-07 12:25:54 | INFO     | DF | Running on torch 1.12.1+cpu 
>
>2022-10-07 12:25:54 |> INFO     | DF | Running on host DESKTOP- 
>
>Traceback (most recent call last):   
>
>File"C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py",
> line 197, in _run_module_as_main
>     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,  
>
> File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py",
> line 87, in _run_code
>     exec(code, run_globals)   
> File "C:\Users\dell\PycharmProjects\django\audio\.venv\Scripts\deepFilter.exe\__main__.py",
> line 7, in <module>   
>
>File "C:\Users\dell\PycharmProjects\django\audio\.venv\lib\site-packages\df\enhance.py",
> line 348, in run
>     main(parser.parse_args())   File "C:\Users\dell\PycharmProjects\django\audio\.venv\lib\site-packages\df\enhance.py",
> line 25, in main
>     model, df_state, suffix = init_df(
>     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,   
>
>File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 505, in run
>     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:   
>
>File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 951, in __init__
>     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   
>
>File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
>     hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args, FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 
>
> The system cannot find the file specified
```

Both of the error specify problem, but I have the `input file` in the specified path, which can be seen below:

[image: Directory]

Comment: Have you tried providing full path instead of only `samples/chat_with_noise.wav` as the error suggests?

Comment: Yes, I tried but same error

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error, you need to modify your envirinment.`subprocess.py`

The path on your computer is at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py

First, you need to locate the file and edit it, then set `shell=True`

```
def __init__(self, args, bufsize=-1, executable=None,
             stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
             preexec_fn=None, close_fds=True,
             shell=True, cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=None,
             startupinfo=None, creationflags=0,
             restore_signals=True, start_new_session=False,
             pass_fds=(), *, user=None, group=None, extra_groups=None,
             encoding=None, errors=None, text=None, umask=-1, pipesize=-1):
```

To get more imformation about, please see the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html)

This solution worked for me, and hope it work for you.